# Java: sorting a generic class with two types

Tags: java, generics, comparator

Suppose the following generic class with 2 types T, U

```
public class Pair<T, U> implements Comparable<T, U>  { //Error 1

   private final T first;
   private final U second;

   public Pair(T first_, U second_) {
      first = first_;
      second = second_;}

   public T getFirst() { return first; }
   public U getSecond() { return second; }
}
```

and the list of its items

```
List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> = new ArrayList<>()
```

that need to be sorted according to the first/second attribute. Unfortunately, the class definition contains some issue, the following error appears:

```
Error 1: wrong number of type arguments
```

How to design the comparator class? This code is probably completely wrong

```
public class SortBySecond implements Comparable <Pair <T, U>> {

    public int compare(final Pair<T, U> p1, final Pair<T, U> p2) //Error 2
    {
        return t1.getSecond().compareTo(t2.getSecond()); //Updated comparator
    }
}

Error 2 : Can not find symbols T, U, V
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think you can compare generic types with `<` and `>`, those only work for primitive types.  Instead try something like `return p1.getSecond().compareTo(p2.getSecond());`.

Comment: How do _you_ want to compare two pairs?

Comment: "that need to be sorted according to the first/second attribute" do you mean that it first needs to be sorted by the first attribute. If the first attribute are the same, sort it by the second one?

Comment: I wouldn't have a generic `Pair` class implement `Comparable`. Who knows if `T` or `U` are comparable? Leave it up to the user to create a custom `Comparator` if they want to sort their pairs, that way they can decide whether to sort by the first field, the second, combine them, or whatever.

Comment: @azurefrog: The comparator has been updated according to your recommendation.

Comment: @Sweeper: I can compare a pair by one of its attributes :-)...

Comment: I am not asking what you _can_ do. What are you supposed to do?

Comment: @Sweeper: Sorry, I understood your comment in the wrong way. I would like to compare the generic type according to the first and then according to the second attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Pair` class should implement `Comparable<Pair<T, U>>` instead of `Comparable<T, U>`, which is a type that does not exist. You should also make sure that `T` and `U` are comparable.

There are lots of useful methods in the [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface to help you compare things. You can use them to implement `Comparable<Pair<T, U>>`. In fact, you don't need to implement `Comparable` to sort the list. You only need to create a `Comparator`!

Here's how to implement `Comparable`:

```
class Pair<T extends Comparable<T>, U extends Comparable<U>> implements Comparable<Pair<T, U>> {
    public int compare(final Pair<T, U> p1, final Pair<T, U> p2)
    {
        // this first compares the first field. If the first fields are the same, the second fields are compared
        // If you have a different requirement, implement it accordingly.
        return Comparator.comparing(Pair::getFirst).thenComparing(Pair::getSecond).compare(p1, p2);
    }
}
```

To sort your list, do:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Pair::getFirst).thenComparing(Pair::getSecond));
```

To sort your list with only the second field, do:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Pair::getSecond));
```

Comment: "In fact, you don't need to implement Comparable to sort the list." Yes but overall you  want to implement `Comparable` only if you have a natural order. And here it is clearly not the case, so `Comparator` makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that your `T` and `U` types extend `Comparable` and make your `Pair` class implement `Comparable<Pair<T,U>>` :

```
public class Pair<T extends Comparable<T>, U extends Comparable<U>> implements Comparable<Pair<T,U>>  {

        private final T first;
        private final U second;

        public Pair(T first_, U second_) {
            first = first_;
            second = second_;}

        public T getFirst() { return first; }
        public U getSecond() { return second; }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Pair<T, U> o) {
            return this.second.compareTo(o.second);
        }
}
```